# Python 3.6: Find first occurance string(entire column value) from dataframe which starts with '$'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have dataframe with 55 columns, want to find first occurance string where column value satrts with '$'

I tried below script, but could not achieve.

```
string = ''
for col in df:
    string=df[col].str.startswith('$')
    if string!='': sys.exit()
```

sample df:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
123 5678    $45678  $5000
54356   768 Rs.5432 6546
```

Expected result: $45678, which is present in 3rd column

Comment: Can you add data sample? All rows contains `&` ?

Comment: Its bit unclear what you are asking please add the sample of columns

Comment: @ jezrael, added...please check

Comment: Do you want the column name or the entire column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create mask first:

```
m = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.startswith('$'))
print (m)
    Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4
0  False  False   True   True
1  False  False  False  False
```

And then get position of first `True` in rows and columns by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for select by [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
print (np.where(m))
(array([0, 0], dtype=int64), array([2, 3], dtype=int64))

idx = np.where(m)[0][0]
col = np.where(m)[1][0]

a = df.iat[idx, col]
$45678
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.char.startswith`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.startswith.html):

```
for col in df:
    if np.any(np.char.startswith(np.asarray(df[col], str), '$')):
        string = col
        break
else:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: I think he has a values of columns that are strings starting with `$`. Its bit unclear

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can use `.loc` and `.iloc` based on condition i.e

```
mask = df.apply(lambda x : x.str.startswith('$').any(),0)
#mask will return the boolean values so using loc we can access the columns
col = df.loc[:,mask].iloc[:,0]
```

Output `col` :

```
0     $45678
1    Rs.5432
Name: Col3, dtype: object
```

```
col[col.str.startswith('$')].values[0]

'$45678'
```